# Redirect to actionmethod/view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have implemented idel time out functionality. Here when the user is idel for 1 min, we redirect the user to login page. We have kept the track of the url that the user was when the auto logout happened. Eg , of the user is on reset password view and if the auto logout happens the url which i get is as follows

```
http://localhost/XYZ.Portal/?returnUrl=%2FXYZ.Portal%2FUser%2FResetPassword
```

the above url is achieved by using the following code

```
'@Url.Action("Login", "User", new { returnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl })'
```

Now when the user logs in again as he is redirected to login page, I am using the following code to redirect him back but the code doesnt seem to work. What am I doing wrong.?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        UserBE user = new UserBE();
        user.Email = formCollection["Email"];
        user.Password = formCollection["Password"];
        user = UserBL.AuthenticateUser(user);
        if (user.AuthenticUser)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["returnUrl"] != null)
            {
                string returnUrl = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["returnUrl"]);
                Redirect(returnUrl );
            }
            else
            {
                Session["Email"] = user.Email;
                return RedirectToAction("DashBoard");
            }
        }
        else
            return View(user);
    }
    return View();
}
```

`[HttpGet]` login action method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login()
{
   return View();
}

returnUrl I get as XYZ.Portal/User/ResetPassword
```

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad : No I dont get any error. I even tried http://www.google.com instead of my returnUrl . It doesnt redirect to google.

Comment: Have you debugged it? are you getting `Request.QueryString["returnUrl"]` null? Where your code is redirecting presently if its not working?

Comment: @TusharGupta I  dont get anything null. Just the redirection fails.

Comment: So redirection fails means? Is it going inside if condition and if yes please remove Server.UrlDecode

Comment: return Redirect(url) this line gets executed but not redirected to desired url.

Comment: You are missing 'return' before Redirect and remove server.urldecode

Comment: I have written return as my previous comment. If I remove server.urldecode, then what to use.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **return** the `RedirectResult`:

```
if (Request.QueryString["returnUrl"] != null)
{
    string returnUrl = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["returnUrl"]);

    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

See [RedirectResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirectresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: instead of Redirect should i write return redirect or just RedirectResult.?

Comment: `return Redirect(returnUrl);` will do.

Comment: Check the value of `string returnUrl` at runtime.

Comment: it is XYZ.Portal/User/ResetPassword as in the question , still I'll check once more and let you know. Plus, when return redirect is getting executed, the control is going back to the [HttpGet] of the login and the Login view is returned. See my edit for my get Login action method.

Comment: Is it `/XYZ.Portal/User/ResetPassword` or `XYZ.Portal/User/ResetPassword`?

Comment: it is /XYZ.Portal/User/ResetPassword

Answer (score 0):

> Not working. Now my URL becomes localhost/XYZ.Portal

In this case you can do 1 of 2 options:

1) Write:

```
string startReturnUrl = "http://www." + your returnUrl
```

or

2) split your returnUrl like:

```
string viewName = returnUrl.Split('/').Last();
```

But I think better change returnUrl to just only Name of View that you need